# List bullets will not position outside in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, html-lists

My webpage I'm building has a right aligned unordered list nav menu, and I want the bullets to align with one another to the left of the menu.  I was able to accomplish this in Chrome and IE by putting the list inside its own DIV; the bullets are displayed outside the div,so I can control their distance from the list by changing the DIV width.  In Firefox, however, the bullets are displayed inside the DIV, and I do not appear to have a way to control them.

See the difference here:
http://s106.photobucket.com/user/El_Ornitorrinco/media/fftrouble.png.html

What's with the discrepancy?  Is there a simple solution, or do I need a completely different approach?  Thanks for your time.

Ricky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Used to this Code**

Define you `a` `tag` `display:block;` and `text-align:right;` as like this

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Eggs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cheese</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fruit</a></li>
 </ul>
```

**Css**

```
ul li, ul{
    list-style:square;
}
ul{
    width:400px;

}
li a{display:block;text-align:right;}
```

[**Live Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/rAt3g/1/)

Comment: This is what I was looking for.  Thank you!  Do you know why Firefox refuses to play nice without display:block ?

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
 <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Milk</a>></li>
    <li><a href="#">Eggs</a>></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cheese</a>></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vegetables</a>></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fruit</a>></li>
 </ul>
```

`CSS`  goes here

```
ul
{
list-style-type: none;
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
text-align: right;
}

li
{
background-image: url(arrow.gif);
background-repeat: no-repeat;
background-position: 100% .4em;
padding-right: .6em;
}
```

If not then please create fiddle for it.

Comment: I was hoping for an answer that wouldn't involve images, although if Firefox won't play nice than I'm not left with much of an option. Here is the code that you can see works fine in Chrome/IE:
<code><div id="nav">
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Milk</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Eggs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Cheese</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Vegetables</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Fruit</a></li>
 </ul> 
</div>
</code>

<code>
#nav {
    width: 150px;
    float: right;
    margin-right: 100px;
}

ul
{
text-align: right;
list-style-type: circle;
}
</code>
http://fiddle.jshell.net/zwY9F/1/